# Minimizing Google Chrome Extension with An On Click Event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am wanting to minimize a google chrome extension pop up window when  a button is clicked.

So far I have tried adding `onclick = "window.close();"` to the tags of the link, and also:

```
document.getElemenetById('minimizewindow').onclick = function () {
    return window.close(); 
};
```

Comment: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Note also that close() has no effect when called on Window objects returned by HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/window/close

Comment: Do you want to minimize or close?

Comment: Hello Norio, Thank you for your reply. I would like to close it

Answer (score 0):

Are you refering to the menu of the extension or a real in Browser pop-up?
Im assuming here you ment the menu:

You can only close things with `Window.close()` which are opened with `Window.open()`.
Reference for Window.close(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close?retiredLocale=de

There is a chance that you cant controll the extension at all. Because chrome protects them for sure. Imagine you try to execute malicious code and it can just controll the Browser extensions.

Here is also a far related question in StackExchange: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193701/is-it-possible-for-page-to-get-your-installed-extensions-through-javascript

I know the answer fits not 100% but is better than probably no one.
Could you comment if this helps you? So if not I can also delete it.

Comment: Hey , thank you for your response. 

I did find an extension that seems to have figured a work around of some sort by using the following:

Comment: var openPermissionPopup = function openPermissionPopup(platformName) {
  var url = "enablePermission.html?platform=".concat(platformName);
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  }, function (tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs.length ? tabs[0] : null;

    if (activeTab) {
      url += "&openerTab=".concat(activeTab.id);
    }

    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: url
    });
    window.close();
  });
};

Comment: var renderPopupIframe = function renderPopupIframe(platformName) {
  document.getElementById(_constants__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__[/* MINIMIZE_BUTTON_ID */ "a"]).onclick = function () {
    return window.close();

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to close the popup with `window.close()`.
I understand the documentation says it can't be done.
[Window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

Below is a sample that closes a popup.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button id="close">Close</button>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
document.getElementById("close").onclick = () => {
  window.close();
}
```